# Alocação de memória e ponteiros

Tags: c, ponteiro, operadores, struct, memória

Estou implementando um Sudoku, porem estou tendo um problema na hora de preenchê-lo.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdbool.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <stdio_ext.h>

  typedef struct grid_info {
    int size;
    int fields_total;
    int* grid;
    int rows_mistakes;
    int column_mistakes;
    int sectors_mistakes;
  } grid;

  void welcome_screen(grid*);
  grid* fill_the_(grid*);

  int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    grid* sudoku = (grid*)malloc(sizeof(grid));

    welcome_screen(sudoku);
    fill_the_(sudoku);

    printf("Sudoku size: %d\n", sudoku->size);
    free(sudoku);
    return 0;
  }

  grid* fill_the_(grid* sudoku) {
    sudoku->grid = malloc(sizeof(sudoku->fields_total));
    for(int row = 0; row < sudoku->size; row += (sudoku->fields_total / sudoku->size)) {
      for(int column = row; column = row + sudoku->size; column++) {
        scanf("%d", &sudoku->grid[column]);
      }
    }
  }

  void welcome_screen(grid* sudoku) {
    printf("Welcome to the sudoku game\n"
           "Please enter the number of sudoku: ");
    scanf("%d", &sudoku->size);
    while (sudoku->size < 2 || sudoku->size >= 10) {
      printf("The sudoku grid can only have size of 2 to 9\n"
             "Please enter the number of sudoku: ");
      scanf("%d", &sudoku->size);
    }
    sudoku->fields_total = pow(sudoku->size, 2);
  }
```

Na hora de preencher a `struct`, parece que ele entra em um *loop* infinito, não sei se fiz certo pra conseguir botar um *index* na *grid* dentro da `struct`.

Comment: Tentei fazer uma resposta, mas está um tanto confuso e complexo o código aconselho você a usar matrizes para representar linhas e colunas. Exemplo de uma matriz seria matriz[row][col], e você cria dois for encapsulado, uma para percorrer as linhas e um outro para percorrer as colunas. E você tem uma variavel dentro da estrutura do tipo inteiro que se chama grid que tem o mesmo nome da estrutura grid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem alguns problemas, o código sequer compila. Eu dei uma boa melhorada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct grid_info {
    int size;
    int fields_total;
    int* grid;
    int rows_mistakes;
    int column_mistakes;
    int sectors_mistakes;
} grid;

void fill_the_(grid* sudoku) {
    sudoku->grid = malloc(sizeof(sudoku->fields_total));
    for (int row = 0; row < sudoku->size; row += (sudoku->fields_total / sudoku->size)) {
        for (int column = row; column < row + sudoku->size; column++) {
         scanf("%d", &sudoku->grid[column]);
        }
    }
}

void welcome_screen(grid* sudoku) {
    do {
        printf("The sudoku grid can only have size of 2 to 9\n"
             "Please enter the number of sudoku: ");
        scanf("%d", &sudoku->size);
    } while (sudoku->size < 2 || sudoku->size >= 10);
    sudoku->fields_total = pow(sudoku->size, 2);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    grid* sudoku = malloc(sizeof(grid));
    welcome_screen(sudoku);
    fill_the_(sudoku);
    printf("Sudoku size: %d\n", sudoku->size);
    free(sudoku);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Pointer.c).

O principal erro estava aqui: `for(int column = row; column < row + sudoku->size; column++) {`. Em geral comparações em um `for` deve ser feitas até que se chegue a uma determinado estado. Em geral os operadores mais usados são `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`. Eventualmente o uso de `==` e `!=` e outras expressões que gerem um booleano podem ser usado. Mas `=` é o operador de atribuição, e embora ele pode ser usada aí em certas situações, **adicionalmente**, raramente, e principalmente neste caso, não é adequado.

Answer (score 3):

O erro está nessa linha:

```
for(int column = row; column = row + sudoku->size; column++)
```

O loop nunca termina pois column não ta sendo comparada, basta alterar para:

```
for(int column = row; column == row + sudoku->size; column++)
```